# How to access Node class from LinkedList directly?

Tags: java, linked-list

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
    llist.head = new LinkedList.Node(1);
    LinkedList.Node second = new LinkedList.Node(2);
    LinkedList.Node third = new LinkedList.Node(3);
    llist.head.next = second;
    second.next = third;
    llist.printList();
}}
```

**LinkedList.java**

```
class LinkedList {
Node head;
static class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node( int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}
public void printList(){
    Node n = head;
    while(n != null) {
        System.out.print(n.data + " ");
        n = n.next;
    }
}}
```

I want to use just Node second = new Node(2) and Node = new Node(3) instead of using LinkedList.Node everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can static import for that.

```
import static java.util.SomeClass.*;
```

or

```
import static java.util.SomeClass.SomeOtherVariable;
```

After static import, you can use SomeOtherVariable directly,

```
SomeOtherVariable second = new SomeOtherVariable(2)
```

Comment: https://graph.org/file/31842a6df765f6f97afa3.png Throwing this

Comment: private static class Node<E>  is private static, you will not be able to access outside of class.

Comment: I cannot understand, I tried making it public static class Node but it didn't help. :/

Comment: this will help you https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers

Comment: Still did not help, I just removed the file and put it all in Main.java. Worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Aight, have it.